# Why am I having the most perfectly looking boot when I run from CD/USB but not from HD?

Tags: installation, live-cd, live-usb, plymouth

I've read the lot of topics on plymouth and nvidia drivers.

However my question is focused on why the difference between live cd and installation?

By "**the perfectly looking boot**" I mean:

- the boot animation starts at the appropriate time (immediately)
- the bootscreen animation resolution matches my screen
- the transition between bootscreen and login/desktop is smooth
- i can start using my desktop with no lagging due to loading that is still being performed

Once I install Ubuntu on my hard drive though, some or all of the 4 points above are not true.

I've been having this issues since I started using Ubuntu extensively which was around version 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

### "the bootscreen animation resolution matches my screen"

That works only if you're using kernel modesetting, which means no proprietary graphics drivers (nvidia or amd fglrx)

Comment: I'm not using proprietary drivers. I just did a clean 11.10 install. Still the same.